# How to take data from model and display on the product page?

Tags: python, django

I am developing an ecommerce website with django, I can not show on the product page (product_detail.html) the dates from Product_details model, from other models I can display dates, for example, from the Product_image model and from Category model I already take dates and display without any problems. It seems that I did all steps right, but I can not display the dates. Please help me.

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ProductListView
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(), name='amd-home'),
    path('product/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='amd-about'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price_old = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}, {self.description}'

class Product_image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.title} image'

class Product_details(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    internal_storage = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    production_year = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    sim_count = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    sim_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    operation_system = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    operation_system_version = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    screen_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    resolution = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    back_camera = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    front_camera = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    battery = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    weigth = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    prosessor = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    security = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    guarantee = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    operator_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    wifi = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    allow_3G = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    allow_4G = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    nfc = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    gps = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    eye_recognition = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    waterproof = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    faceID = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    shockproof = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.title} details'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product, Product_image, Product_details

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

def product_detail(request, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    photos = Product_image.objects.filter(product=product)
    details = Product_details.objects.filter(product=product)
    context = {'product':product,'photos':photos, 'details':details,}
    return render(request, 'product/product_detail.html', context)
```

**template product_detail.html**
Below is my template file, this is a very large file, so I only insert the element where I refer to this model. I want notice {{product.brand.name}} {{product.title}} is normally visible on screen, but {{details.ram}} / {{details.internal_storage}} is not visible.

```
<h2>{{ product.brand.name }} {{ product.title }} {{ details.ram }} / {{details.internal_storage}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product_details is a child table, so in your view, details is a queryset, it may contain 0 or multiple records

```
details = Product_details.objects.filter(product=product)
```

to display it, you need to loop through `details` in your template

```
{% if details %}
<br>details
{% for detail in details %}
<br>{{ detail.ram }} / {{detail.internal_storage}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```